# R exams package weird behaviour with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, r-exams

I have noted to strange behaviour in the R exams package when I load the dplyr library. the below example only works if I explicitly call the dplyr namespace, as indicated in the comments. notice that the error only occurs in a fresh session, i.e. you need to restart R in order to see what I see. You need to place the below in a file `exam.Rmd`, then call

````
library(exams)
library(dplyr)
exams2html("exam.Rmd")  # in pwd

# this is exam.Rmd
```{r datagen,echo=FALSE,results='hide',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
df = data.frame(i = 1:4, y = 1:4, group = paste0("g",rep(1:2,2)))
# works:
b2 = diff(dplyr::filter(df,group!="g1")$y)
b3 = diff(dplyr::filter(df,group!="g2")$y)
# messes up the complete exercise:
# b2 = diff(filter(df,group!="g1")$y)
# b3 = diff(filter(df,group!="g2")$y)
nq = 2
questions <- solutions <- explanations <- rep(list(""), nq)
type <- rep(list("num"),nq)

questions[[1]] = "What is the value of $b_2$ rounded to 3 digits?"
questions[[2]] = "What is the value of $b_3$ rounded to 3 digits?"
solutions[[1]] = b2
solutions[[2]] = b3
explanations[[1]] = paste("You have you substract the conditional mean of group 2 from the reference group 1. gives:",b2)
explanations[[2]] = paste("You have you substract the conditional mean of group 3 from the reference group 1",b3)
```


Question
========
You are given the following dataset on two variables `y` and `group`. 

```{r showdata,echo=FALSE}
# kable(df,row.names = FALSE,align = "c")
df
```

some text with math

$y_i = b_0 + b_2 g_{2,i}  + b_3 g_{3,i} + e_i$

```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(unlist(questions), markup = "markdown")
```

Solution
========

```{r sollist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(unlist(explanations), markup = "markdown")
```

Meta-information
================
extype: cloze
exsolution: `r paste(solutions,collapse = "|")`
exclozetype: `r paste(type, collapse = "|")`
exname: Dummy Manual computation
extol: 0.001
````

Comment: Totally not weird/strange. `?exams2html` or go to https://github.com/cran/exams/blob/master/R/exams2html.R#L1-L5. There's an `envir` parameter. It's `NULL` by default so everything is going to run in a fresh environment when you call that function. That means it knows not of `dplyr`. Either put the `library()` call for `dplyr` _in_ the Rmd or pass in the calling environment. I'd do the former. If you're worried about the package startup messages, suppress them. `filter()` just happens to be a `stats` function that the tidyverse brazenly overloaded.

Comment: @hrbrmstr not very helpful. 1) putting `library(dplyr)` in the Rmd file does not change a thing. 2) `?exams2html` says *envir: argument passed to xweave (which passes it to knit)*. now, package will be visible in any env: `e=new.env();library(dplyr);exists("arrange",envir=e)` 3) I ask a question on SO precisely s.t. I *don't* have to go and look at the source code. 4) This is a great package and I'm very grateful to the devs. Docs could be more complete, as always. not a critique, a fact. 5) end.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for raising this issue and to @hrbrmstr for explanation of one part of the problem. However, one part of the explanation is still missing:

- Of course, the root of the problem is that both `stats` and `dplyr` export different `filter()` functions. And it can depend on various factors which function is found first.
- In an interactive session it is sufficient to load the packages in the right order with `stats` being loaded automatically and `dplyr` subsequently. Hence this works:
  `library("knitr")`
  `library("dplyr")`
  `knit("exam.Rmd")`
- It took me a moment to figure out what is different when you do:
  `library("exams")`
  `library("dplyr")`
  `exams2html("exam.Rmd")`
- It turns out that in the latter code chunk `knit()` is called by `exams2html()` and hence the `NAMESPACE` of the `exams` package changes the search path because it fully imports the entire `stats` package. Therefore, `stats::filter()` is found before `dplyr::filter()` unless the code is evaluated in an environment where `dplyr` was loaded such as the `.GlobalEnv`. (For more details see the answer by @hrbrmstr)

As there is no pressing reason for the `exams` package to import the entire `stats` package, I have changed the `NAMESPACE` to import only the required functions selectively (which does not include the `filter()` function). Please install the development version from R-Forge:

```
install.packages("exams", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

And then your .Rmd can be compiled without `dplyr::...` just by including `library("dplyr")` - either within the .Rmd or before calling `exams2html()`. Both should work now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Using your `exams.Rmd`, this is the source pane where I'm about to hit cmd-enter:

[image]

(I added `quiet=FALSE` so I could see what was going on).

Here's the console output after cmd-enter:

[image]

And here's the output:

[image]

If you read *all the way through* to the help on `knit`:

- `envir`: *Environment in which code chunks are to be evaluated, for example, `parent.frame()`, `new.env()`, or `globalenv()`)*.

So `parent.frame()` or `globalenv()` is required vs what you did (you don't seem to fully understand environments). You get `TRUE` from your `exists()` call because *by default* `inherits` is `TRUE` in the `exists` function and that tells the function to *"[search] the enclosing frames of the environment"* (from the help on `exists`.

And, you should care deeply about source code and triaging errors. You're using a programming language and open source software and you are right that the `library(dplyr)` didn't work inside the Rmd due to some terrible code choices in this *"great"* package and that you don't want pointed out since you don't want to look at source code.

End, as I can do no more for you. I just hope others benefit from this.

Comment: thanks, that's much more helpful! I have forgotten about the `inherits` argument, so that clarifies a lot. The fact that moving the `library(dplyr)` into the Rmd didn't make it work confused me a lot (you say it shouldn't be the case!), that's why I called it strange/weird. I found your initial comment a bit abrasive, for no good reason that I could see. That's why I responded like I did. The package resolves a lot of problems for me, hence it's great. I apologise if I interpreted your initial comment wrongly, and thanks for the complete answer.